# Improve Tag Wiki visibility

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Many tags have extensive and detailed tag wikis with many useful guidelines for new questions, etc, but very, very few users seem to be able to discover the tag wikis.

Is there a way to make them easier to discover?  Or should tag wikis be abandoned as a waste of effort?

I'm opening this as a discussion thread, so I don't have any immediate suggestions, but I'm thinking along the following lines.

When newcomers ask their first questions in a tag, it would be useful if they had quick and easy access to the tag wiki.  However, not all tag wikis contain information which is useful in this scenario.  I don't think tagging the tag wiki (ha!) would work very well, and I don't particularly like the idea of having a designated section (say, a headline **Question Guidelines** at a particular level) but then, what would work better?

On the other hand, if tag wikis cannot be made more prominent, are we wasting our time by trying to improve them?  Perhaps we should be spending that time on creating canonical questions or something instead.

Comment: Tangentially, I note with some glee that the "tag wiki" isn't actually a proper wiki.  As a wiki user, I would like to be able to create new pages I can link to without creating new tags; then the tag wikis could be refactored into properly interlinked chunks on related topics.  But if I assess the SO developers' comments here and elsewhere correctly, any change to the tag wikis would be more likely to remove them rather than develop them into a first-class SO citizen.

Comment: I've been here since the beginning and I have no idea how to edit tags....

Comment: @womp I take that as a supporting vote, rather than a request for support.

Comment: yep - I'm agreeing with you.  I had to come to meta and it still didn't make it any more obvious.   I finally figured it out though.  :)

Comment: Is "Tag Info" what is meant by Tag Wiki?

Comment: @CPerkins I guess we are talking about the same thing, yes.  The misnomer of a term "tag wiki" used to be more prominent in the web interface IIRC but it's still visible e.g. when hovering over the "learn more..." label on a tag's search page.

Comment: Now with Documentation being the new thing competing for "not really a wiki but clearly trying to be one", I suppose this should also mention the possibility of interlinking Documentation with an extended tag description, and vice versa. (In my limited experience, even interlinking Documentation with itself is a bit of a struggle.)

Comment: As a newer user, I see an extremely high value in the tag excerpts, but a somewhat lower value in the extended tag info wikis. I would be in favor of anything that improves their visibility, __especially__ a tool that wold improve the ability to find & fix incomplete tag excerpts.