# Markdown shortcut "magic link" to tag info [info:tagname]

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki, magic-links

I frequently find myself linking to a tag's info page for background. This is currently hard; you have to memorize or rediscover `/tags/<tagname>/info` and compose a descriptive link text.

This is arguably an under-utilized resource at the moment, perhaps not only because it is hard to link to; but one way to get better exposure in the tags which already have amazing tag info pages would be to facilitate easy linking from answers and comments.

The quality of tag info pages (somewhat misleadingly aka "tag wikis") is variable; but many tags I participate in on Stack Overflow have excellent FAQ resources, background, and troubleshooting tips on that page.

When linking, I have found that I often want to include the fact that the link is to a local Stack Oveflow resource, not to an external page; so the template I am currently mentally applying and manually entering is

```
[the Stack Overflow <tagname> info page](/tags/<tagname>/info)
```

It would be fabulous if an editing shortcut like `[info:<tagname>]` could be made available to produce (something like) this text, somewhat similarly to how `[tag:<tagname>]` is available for linking to a tag's questions page. (The meta tag for this mechanism is apparently [magic-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magic-links).)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292364/improve-tag-wiki-visibility also by yours truly.

Comment: Why is `[tag:whatever]` not sufficient? Getting to the info page from the tag page is trivial. I would just use `the SO [tag:tagname] info page` in your example.

Comment: @jpmc26 It's obscure in the best case, and doesn't work at all in mobile.

Answer (score 6):

I think `[tag:tag-name]` is mostly useless. I can't find a single use case scenario, where linking to list of questions on that tag helps anyone. It neither helps the askers nor the answerers. I propose the magic link of `[tag:tag-name]` be redirected to the tag info/tag wiki page instead.

- Existing links are not broken, but redirected to that tag wiki
- I think tag wikis are the greatest collection of resources related to that tag. Any link in answers/comments provide askers with valuable FAQs, resources and tips.
- This is much easier than creating a new magic link. Compared to the simple work done, Stackoverflow's existing links are greatly improved and it greatly reduces the trouble for existing users to link to tag wikis.

I highly recommend that this feature request be implemented.

Comment: It is useful in the search box, but that's separate from what is being proposed here. I really like this idea; +1

Comment: @tripleee The syntax used in the searchbox is different: `[tag]` vs `[tag:tag-name]`.

Comment: *"Existing links are not broken, but redirected to that tag wiki"* There are links that intend to go to tagged questions, especially on meta and their tag burnination/cleanup requests.

Comment: @gre_gor Even in meta, I believe most tag links would benefit from  having it direct to the info page. When moderators or members are clicking the tag button, they're looking for more info about the tag than the questions. Moreover, the questions tab is just 1 click away. If there was a vote, I'd vote to keep the basic redirect to tag info page rather than the questions tab. I believe it would benefit almost everyone in the community including cleanup/burnination efforts.

Answer (score 3):

Nowhere near the full solution you are looking for, but you can get a link to the tag page, without typing, by hovering over the tag.  The box that opens has a link to the info page in it like:

[image]

Comment: But that only works if the tag is on the question already. If you want to divert a lost C++ user to a better world you might want to say: `[info:vba]`

Comment: And none of this is feasible in the mobile view.

Comment: @tripleee, Is there anything feasible in the mobile view?  :-)

Comment: @rene I don't know whether to upvote your comment for "lost C++ user" , or to burn it, burn it with fire for the rest.

Comment: I routinely visit Stack Overflow on my phone, and often post comments or answers while on mobile. There are usability problems, yes, but most of them are caused by platform limitations, not by Stack Overflow's mobile skin. Whether or not some features were made harder to use on mobile on purpose is neither here nor there anyway.