# Related question list is REALLY irrelevant

Tags: discussion, bug, related-questions

I suddenly started seeing a section called "related questions".  Now, I'm ok with this as a concept, but the implementation here is picking horrible results.  For example, [Why should I integrate React Dev Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75814469/why-should-i-integrate-react-dev-tools).

Question:  "Why should I integrate React Dev Tools?"

Related questions:

- How can I save an activity state using the save instance state?
- Vertically align text to top within a UILabel
- How do I remedy "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." warning?

Those are nowhere close.  They're not even close to being close.  They don't even match keywords with the question.  If you can't provide something that makes a relatively good guess, this feature detracts from the site rather than adds to it.  It shouldn't be shown unless your confidence level is high enough.

Comment: Congratulation, you just found a solution for https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5551/random-question-button :)

Comment: But think of the _engagement_! And the click-through-rate (CTR)! And how happy the **investors** become of those numbers!

Comment: "*I suddenly started seeing a section called "related questions"*" related questions have always been there for a long time, but it's now more noticeable due to the recent [related questions within the answers list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423143/2821954).

Comment: Just change the title to "Almost Certainly Unrelated Questions" and we have a winner.

Comment: @CodeCaster [Won't someone PLEASE think of the investors!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=phSxxVJCZsc)

Comment: But why phrase this like a lecture rather than an actual bug report though? Yeah it doesn't work reliably. I think we'll live.

Comment: @Gimby Because it was a discussion originally and not a bug report.  As for living-  I think with the new prominent placement it REALLY detracts from the site.  In the sidebar it was ok-ish.  Now it's so bad that if I wasn't a longtime user I'd have little faith in the site's ability to answer me, if that's what it thought was related.  A new user and low skill user is going to see those and get confused and lost.If it's that unreliable, remove it until it works.

Comment: @Gimby Shouldn't the developers of a programming site at least minimally test their changes before inflicting them on live users?

Comment: it's often easy to look at a change strictly from the PoV of data and see that the change is *obviously* having a major impact that you intended the change to have while not seeing the bigger picture or side effects that the change can have. Why would SO assume that the related questions being presented are bad if the posts being presented are overwhelmingly upvoted? It's easy, as someone whose been here for 12 years, to see that a post having 2k+ upvotes more often indicates that it's going to be a question with 10 pages of awful answers rather than a good Q&A pair. Why should SO assume that?

Comment: The *questions* are (supposed to be) related, not the *list*, => "*Related questions list is [...]*"

Answer (score 2):

Last year, [we kicked off the Content Discovery Initiative](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421072/announcing-the-content-discovery-initiative) to improve the Related Questions module. [This initiative has many stages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423798/content-discovery-initiative-3-29-update-related-questions-using-a-machine-lear), and is looking at not only where the module is on the page, but also the relevancy of the content that is recommended.

Recently, we initiated [an experiment incorporating machine learning (ML) to see how it would improve the relevance of related questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423886/do-you-observe-increased-relevance-of-related-questions-with-our-machine-learnin). We are monitoring this closely to find out how this change has affected the questions that are being suggested, and so we really value your feedback here.