# A/B testing the separation of The Overflow Blog from the Community Bulletin (testing concluded)

Tags: discussion, design, blog, community-bulletin, a-b-testing

**Update Feb 9**: Testing has concluded.

**Update Jan 30**: Test is now active on Stack Overflow for anonymous users.

### Background

As part of the [Content Discovery initiative](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421072/announcing-the-content-discovery-initiative), we’re announcing the next experiment. In this test, we will separate the Overflow Blog posts from the Community Bulletin into its own dedicated section. This will happen on Stack Overflow and not on the rest of the Exchange.

In [this year’s Developer Survey](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022/), more than 70,000 developers told us how they learn, which tools they’re using, and what they want. Specifically, when it comes to online learning, [75% of respondents selected blogs](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022/#section-learning-to-code-online-resources-to-learn-how-to-code) as one of the top resources for learning how to code, in addition to reading technical documentation and browsing Stack Overflow. This is up 25% year-over-year from the [2021 Developer Survey results](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021#section-experience-learning-how-to-code).

While the results speak generally about learning through blog sites, the Stack Overflow blog includes a variety of content that appeal to a wider audience, specifically the [Code for a Living column](https://stackoverflow.blog/code-for-a-living/). Historically, blog posts on Stack Overflow and across the network sites have been combined with Featured and Hot Meta posts in the Community Bulletin, which pertain to a smaller percentage of users who want to stay updated on new and upcoming changes on the platform.

We think it’s valuable for users who are interested in reading blog content to have a dedicated space for this type of content which creates more opportunities for future expansion. As we move towards a more contextualized, and personalized experience, we hope that carving out a dedicated section for blog content will better serve users who find it interesting and relevant.

### Experiment goals and success criteria

The goal of this experiment is to determine whether creating a new dedicated section for blog content will result in any incremental engagement to blog posts.

We will consider this experiment a success if a variant does not perform worse than the current engagement. We will also monitor the clickthrough rate (CTR) of the Community Bulletin, which includes Featured on Meta and Hot Meta posts.

### How we’re conducting the test

We will conduct two separate blog module experiments. Each experiment will test different background colors to determine which one performs better in terms of engagement.

**The experiment will be conducted on Stack Overflow question pages for anonymous users only.** It will target 60% of the traffic that will be split evenly between the control and three variant groups. Users in the control group will continue to see blog posts within the Community Bulletin. The remaining population will be presented with one of the variants.

The first version closely resembles the existing design in the Community Bulletin. The second design is visually more appealing with the addition of a thumbnail.

Here are screenshots for both designs:

[image: Screenshot showing Stack Overflow Blog section of right sidebar, above the community bulletin – variant A: including blog post titles only (with gray background)]

*Figure 1: Stack Overflow Blog variant A with blog title*

[image: Screenshot showing Stack Overflow Blog section – variant B: including blog post titles and thumbnails (with gray background)]

*Figure 2: Stack Overflow Blog variant B with title and thumbnail*

[image: Screenshot showing Stack Overflow Blog section – additional background variants: both versions above, with black background yellow background]

*Figure 3: Additional background variants*

Once the experiment concludes, we will analyze the results and share with Meta.

Comment: Can we also get a label for articles from partners? they aren't far removed from sponsored content.

Comment: The quality of some Overflow Blog posts is really low. I'm not sure that promoting this blog is really a good idea.

Comment: @Dada Calling it "really low" is a compliment

Comment: _Not worse than the current variant_ is a very low bar to meet if you want to use more of my screen real estate and bandwidth by adding images. In this "more personalized experience", I'd hope to see less images that don't interest me

Comment: Hooray! Now it will be easier for my userscript to make the blog links invisible with CSS.

Comment: My experience has been you really need to pick and choose your programming blogs. Some are little more than the writer working on earning a Dunning-Kruger merit badge for their Scout uniform. Directing folks to blogs of good quality is a worthwhile  effort.

Comment: When does this go live? Is the A/B test already running? If not, when does it start? Can you please update the post to specify explicitly?

Comment: I'm not sure the [75% from this year](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022/#section-learning-to-code-online-resources-to-learn-how-to-code) can be compared to the [60% from last year](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021#section-experience-learning-how-to-code), as the options were ___much___ more fine-grained this year. I remember not selecting _"Other online resources (videos, blogs, etc)"_ because I absolutely hate video tutorials for tech.

Comment: Truth, that. I'm too impatient to watch the video looking for the bit of information I need. I can do an eyeball scan for keywords almost as fast as I can press pgdn. not so easy to do with a video.

Comment: @CodyGray The experiment goes live today and will run until February 1.

Comment: Hey, @Salmon_of_Wisdom; thanks for the response! The experiment is only going to run for 2 days (or 1, depending on how you count)? That seems like a *very* short period of time. Did you mean March 1?

Comment: @CodyGray Nope! Some of the experiments in the Initiative will run for short intervals, the space of a few days.

Comment: Please post a separate question instead of editing in updates to your existing questions.

Comment: @TravisJ I don't see how that would be appropriate in this case. They're not really announcing anything new. Informing us when the feature described here has been turned on/off *is* an update to this question, not a new question. A new question would be nothing more than a stub linking back to this. That doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @CodyGray - I guess that depends on if this is the final version of this post. These questions are being treated more as bulletin board posts than question and answer posts. It isn't really inline with the use of the site.

Comment: It's an announcement of a site change and/or feature, @TravisJ. We've always used Meta as the place for that. It's not traditional Q&A, but nothing about Meta is traditional. If staff was using this same post as a bulletin board for announcing *multiple* site changes/features, then I'd agree that would be inappropriate. However, this has so far always stayed focused on a single feature. The only updates have been to give specific dates of when the change has been made, and when it was reverted back. Those are helpful details to have here, and they rightly belong as updates.

Comment: This probably isn't the best place for this discussion, but doesn't it seem that there used to be blog posts paired with requested feedback, in the sort of "always" sense? It certainly feels like recently meta is more of a list of blog posts than any sort of actual discussion about how the site itself works. This is what is happening with regards to the site, so it isn't exactly off topic in itself, but the nature of the posting, where it is just an explanation paired with a constant stream of edits, isn't exactly how it's always been... imho

Answer (score 18):

I do think it's a good idea to break the blog content out of the more important site-specific bulletin as more and more important topics need to be displayed there, however I'm not so sure it should be on top? Surely increasing community engagement within the community would be more important than whisking them away to read content reposted from other blogging platforms.

Comment: I think this is a good point. I'll share this back as an idea for future testing.

Answer (score 3):

> Once the experiment concludes, we will analyze the results and share with Meta.

> Update Feb 9: Testing has concluded.

When?