# Community bulletin is not present if filters are used (other than tags)

Tags: bug, feature-request, search

I've noticed a weird thing: community bulletin is not showing if any non-tag filters are applied. I can see it on the main page, on the question page, when filtering by tags either:

> [image]

However, once I [apply any other filters](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20or%20%5Bregex%5D%20or%20%5Bcss%5D%20or%20%5Bmysql%5D%20or%20%5Bphp%5D%20score%3A3%20is%3Aq&searchOn=3) (e.g. score or post type) community bulletin vanishes

> [image]

Considering that I mostly browse with score filters, I would like the community bulletin to show in this case

I'm not sure whether absence of bulletin is a bug or a feature: these pages seem to be different in many other ways (the first one is `/tagged`, the second one is `/search` results), so I believe I should make it a feature request, since why not - I see no particular reason to omit the bulletin from `/search` page

You could say that `/tagged` and `/search` serve an entirely different purpose, though I wouldn't agree with you for this particular case: in some tags it's mostly a waste of time to browse newest questions without score filters

Comment: Maybe related to: [A/B testing the separation of The Overflow Blog from the Community Bulletin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422887/5515060)

Comment: Also which browser an OS are you using? Additionally do you have any active userscripts / ad blockers installed

Comment: @Lino checked no userscripts, on Safari / Chrome Mac, although I don't think it matters, could you please check [if you see bulletin here?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20or%20%5Bregex%5D%20or%20%5Bcss%5D%20or%20%5Bmysql%5D%20or%20%5Bphp%5D%20score%3A3%20is%3Aq&searchOn=3)

Comment: I can reproduce the behaviour, on both pages. And I'm using Chrome 109.0.5414.121 on Windows 10

Comment: That's usual I think. Tag and search pages have always behaved substantially different, with search pages having ads more up top, not loading in new questions, and lacking various filters such as bountied by default